# get the actual function when mocking the entire module

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I have mocked a third party library using `jest.genMockFromModule('winston');`
from this point on wherever I require `winston`, if I `console.log(winston)` the mocked functions are also coming. But it should come only in the test case file only.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
__mocks__
   winston.js
const winston = jest.genMockFromModule('winston');
```

logger.js

```
const winston = require('winston')

console.log(winston) // object consist of mockFunctions
```

Comment: whatever you export should come in your import. How's your winston.js file? can you share the rest?

Answer (score 0):

> wherever I require `winston`, if I `console.log(winston)` the mocked functions are also coming

You created a [Manual mock for a Node module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) by creating `__mocks__/winston.js`, which means that `winston` "will be **automatically** mocked".

*Note that [mocking a Node module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) behaves differently than [mocking a user module](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) or mocking a core `Node` module because the module is mocked **automatically** and calling `jest.mock` is not required.*

In other words, because `__mocks__/winston.js` exists, that mock will **automatically** be returned from `require('winston')` in *any* of the code run during your tests.

---

> I have mocked a third party library using `jest.genMockFromModule('winston');`

Calling [`jest.genMockFromModule`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestgenmockfrommodulemodulename) is unnecessary in this situation since `winston` is mocked automatically.

In fact, calling `jest.genMockFromModule` ends up using "the automatic mocking system to generate a mocked version" of the module returned by requiring `winston`, which ends up being your mock at `__mocks__/winston.js`.

In other words, in this situation `jest.genMockFromModule('winston');` ends up returning an automatic mock of your manual mock.

---

> What am I doing wrong here?

The mock at `__mocks__/winston.js` will be returned by `require('winston')`.

To require the actual module during a test use [`jest.requireActual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestrequireactualmodulename):

```
const winstonMock = require('winston');  // this will return the mock

const winston = jest.requireActual('winston');  // this will return the actual module
```

Notes:

- `jest.requireActual` was added in version [21.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#jest-2100)
- `jest.requireActual` *did not work properly for Node modules* until it was fixed with [PR 7404](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/7404) which was released in version [24.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2400)

Comment: i have tried the jest.requireActual but still throwing error

Comment: i have posted the entire code , here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502290/testing-the-logger-using-jest-customformat-with-the-default-printf , can you suggest me what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Even if make jest.requireActualModel and make a console.log(winston) it shows the mocked properties also

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS what version of `Jest` are you using?